# Bootstrap-Datetimepicker: How to Remove Year Number From Month Picker

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to remove year number from top title of month picker  like the image given below:
[image]

I did tried with `viewMode: 'months'` but didn't work.How Can I do this.please help
Here is the Source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Review Sample Month Only</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
      
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({       
         format: 'MM',
                 viewMode: 'months'    
             });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body >
      <div class="container"  >
         <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary"  >
               <div class="panel-heading" >
                  <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">Review Sample Month Only</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" >
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2"  for="datetimepicker" >Month:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <div class='input-group date'>
                              <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker' name= "datetimepicker" placeholder="MM"/>
                              <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                              </span>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                           <button type="submit" id="button1" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>                           
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Try this:-

```css
.picker-switch{
display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Review Sample Month Only</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
      
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({       
         format: 'MM',
                 viewMode: 'months'    
             });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body >
      <div class="container"  >
         <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary"  >
               <div class="panel-heading" >
                  <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">Review Sample Month Only</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" >
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2"  for="datetimepicker" >Month:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <div class='input-group date'>
                              <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker' name= "datetimepicker" placeholder="MM"/>
                              <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                              </span>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                           <button type="submit" id="button1" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>                           
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vikash Pandey It worked.Simple and Nice solution.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue and instead went with the Bootstrap Datepicker instead of date time picker. I was able to remove the year selection by setting the minViewMode and maxViewMode to "months".

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Modified Example using datepicker:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'MM',
        minViewMode: 'months',
        maxViewMode: 'months',
        startView: 'months'
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Review Sample Month Only</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
      
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $('#datepicker').datepicker({       
                 format: 'MM',
                 minViewMode: 'months',
                 maxViewMode: 'months',
                 startView: 'months'
             });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body >
      <div class="container"  >
         <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary"  >
               <div class="panel-heading" >
                  <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">Review Sample Month Only</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" >
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2"  for="datetimepicker" >Month:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <div class='input-group date'>
                              <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datepicker' name= "datepicker" placeholder="MM"/>
                              <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                              </span>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                           <button type="submit" id="button1" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>                           
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just use maxViewMode: 0,

```
    $('#sandbox-container .input-daterange').datepicker({
    maxViewMode: 0,
    todayBtn: true,
    calendarWeeks: true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.switch{ visibility: hidden !important; }
```